# How to dowload multiple dependencies in Gradle with different classifiers?

Tags: maven, gradle

how can I tell gradle to download multiple dependencies with different classifiers?
It just takes the last entry:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10:natives-linux-amd64'
    compile 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10:natives-windows-i586'
    ..
```

I tested the same with maven and there it gets all dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc10</version>
  <classifier>natives-windows-i586</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jogl-all</artifactId>
  <version>2.0-rc10</version>
  <classifier>natives-linux-amd64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there:

```
dependencies{
    compile: 'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10',
             'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10:natives-linux-amd64',
             'org.jogamp.jogl:jogl-all:2.0-rc10:natives-windows-i586'


}
```

[via Gradle Doc](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:module_dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example shown in the [Gradle documentation](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) under the 'Classifiers' section:

```
    otherConf group: 'org.gradle.test.classifiers', name: 'service', version: '1.0', classifier: 'jdk14'
```